# Remove too deep folders in bash on OSX

Tags: directory, subdirectory, rm, recursive-regex

a program created folders recursively. it is too deep, the full path string length is longer than the MAX (getconf ARG_MAX), for example:
/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C//A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C/A/B/C
…… 
so "sudo rm -fr /A" says "Bad address".

How to create a script to deal with it?
Thanks,

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. I got a couple of Directory not empty errors but I just reran the command and everything removed itself.

Comment: This command works for me: `sudo find . -name A* -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

I guess you could create a command line tool with Xcode (file -> new project -> command line tool, insert code, then click the "run" toolbar button).

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/a/b/c/d/..."];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3085367 why not? It's free and comes with a ton of useful stuff (especially the command line tools). Anybody who uses bash should install Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a separate disk with its own filesystem mounted at /A, unmount it and reformat it.

If not, run something like this (very untested):

```
cd /A
```

then

```
cd A || cd B || cd C && rm -rf A* B* C*
```

and keep executing it, hitting up arrow to repeat and executing again till it works...

Good luck!